# How can I detect taps to a specific area/rect of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewController that is using 4 custom UITableViewCell's.

2 of these custom cell's need a special behaviour.

Rather the detecting if a user selected a row/cell via didSelectRowAtIndexPath... I need to detect a tap more specifically.

For example, one of my custom cells is basically 2 buttons. A button on the left of the cell, and a button on the right.

1) Is the best way to do this, to just hook up the button's delegates to my viewcontroller, so the buttons work, or do I want to try and detect a specific rect/area that user tapped in?

Comment: So, the question is "I have a button on a cell. How can I tell if it was pressed?"

Comment: @Stonz2 yeah, how can I do that. After I first initialize the cell I would a) hook up the delegate for the button, correct? And then b) I don't have a IBAction for the button. How do I detect it's tap?

Answer (score 2):

Hook up the buttons, that's what they're for

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your tableview's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(methodToCallWhenPressed)];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[cell.button addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

You will also need to create an `IBOutlet` from the button in the custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just use target-action to observe the buttons. If you are having trouble with the cell eating touch events it should not, try overriding `-hitTest:withEvent:`.

Comment: Do you have to create a delegate on each cell, so that when the IBAction for the button on the custom UITableViewCell is tapped, it can send back some information to the TableViewController that it was tapped? How will I know which cell the button was tapped on?

Comment: A delegate could work for notifying the controller of the event. As for how to identify the cells: just add a property that the controller sets on them, possibly even the index path if it's static content.

Answer (score 0):

You could user a UILabel instead if you don't feel confortable with UIButton. For example, You could add 2 UILabels on each side of the Custom UITableViewCell, resize them to fill the area you would like, then add 2 UITapGesturesRecognizers. I leave you here the steps:

- Add 2 UILabels to the custom cell using the interface builder
- Go to the Attributes Inspector tab, and find "User interaction enable" and enable it. (Do this for each UILabel)
- Connect the UILabels to the Custom cell Controller (IBOutlet)
- Add one UITapGesturesRecongnizer to each UiLabel
- Create a Delegate to pass the Touch event from Custom cell class to TableView Controller to handle the Touch.

and thats it!

i'll leave here you a picture of how the Custom Cell could be

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u97n9yqtgd8x196/label.jpg?dl=0

let me know if you need something else!

Good luck.